# undefined reference to __android_log_print

Tags: android, android-ndk

This question exists, but it was unable to fix my problem.  I'm getting an undefined reference to __android_log_print but I have the include header

`#include <android/log.h>`

and my Android.mk file has

`LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog`

`LOCAL_LDLIBS := -landroid`

I've also tried with just the -llog, to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code, the second line *overrides* the first.  If you really need -landroid,  use

```
LOCAL_LDLIB +=-landroid
```

Most likely, the `-L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib` part should be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

add this in mk file:

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libutils libcutils

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog \
                -landroid
```

Comment: Adding `libutils` and `libcutils` to `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` was necessary for me. +1