# undefined reference to __android_log_print error

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, android-studio, build-error

There are some questions like this one but none of the solutions provided does the trick.
Build outputs the error from the title when building the app with two modules in it. One of the modules has the native code file.

I checked a lot of threads, all of them suggesting inclusion of the -llog. 
Similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154245/undefined-reference-to-android-log-print/24531719#24531719).

my Android.mk:

```
   LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

   include $(CLEAR_VARS)

   LOCAL_MODULE    := com_couchbase_touchdb_TDCollateJSON
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_couchbase_touchdb_TDCollateJSON.cpp
   LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -landroid -llog -ldl -L$(LOCAL_PATH)

   include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I also have the header `<android/log.h>` included into the .cpp file, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Please post the complete clean log of `ndk-build V=1`.

Comment: @AlexCohn, I've put a pause to that project. Thank You for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is not `__android_log_print` but something else that looks similar in your font, for example, `__andriod_log_prlnt` (2 typos). In a C++ project there's name mangling and probably one of the files (it may be even an .h file) misses the header (that is, the order of #includes may be important). IIRC the order of `-L`/`-l` switches also is important, but probably it is not the case here.

I would start with the hello-jni sample in the NDK and add logging to it; then, I would gradually add the application code. If everything worked after that, the next step would be to move the `jni/` folder into your application project, otherwise you'd know what step you did before it broke.

Just in case:

```
#include <android/log.h>
#define LOGD(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG  , "~~~~~~", __VA_ARGS__)
#define DLOG(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG  , "~~~~~~", __VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: Thank you @18446744073709551615. I've put a pause to that project since I have another, more important one. As soon as I check that You will be notified. Again, thank You.